# Why does this loop always return false?

Tags: java, if-statement, return

```
    boolean check = false;
    for(int i = 0; i == 16; i++){
        if(i == i)
            {
                System.out.println("true");
                check = true;   
            }
        else{
                check = false;
        }
    }
        return check;   
    }
```

I've changed my if-statement for the sake of not having to post loads of code but my question is, why does it still return check as false, even though in the first loop the if-statement is correct, it should read if(0 == 0) which is true why does it not return check as true?

Just noticed that if i remove the loop, it works :/ any reasons why?

Thank You!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your loop condition is wrong. Consider this flow of execution:

```
for (int i = 0; i == 16; ++i)
```

1. Initialize `i` to `0`
2. Check if `i == 16` (which is false)
3. Exit loop

so the loop body is never executed.

You should write `for (int i = 0; i <= 16; ++i)`

Answer (score 3):

Because you never enter in the for loop, it should be:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 16; i++){
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i == 16; i++){
```

You are telling enter the loop only when `i=16`  where i assigned to  `0`

Answer (score 0):

This kind of conditions are suitable for loop ... until structure, as others said you never enter the loop so use :

```
 for(int i = 0; i == 16; i++) { ... }
```

or if you insist on a structure like loop... until(cond.) or do-while(!cond.) :

```
int i = 0;
do{
    if(i == i)
        {
            System.out.println("true");
            check = true;   
        }
    else{
            check = false;
    }
}while( ++i != 16 );
```

that is not readable at all (at least I think so) and I think it's not convenient for any Java programmer.

Answer (score 0):

I like this question its my first code i see on this site clearly your condition never runs because i never meets the condition i == 16 so the loop never runs. 
try i <= 16
try this

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 16; i++){
```